# 403 forbidden nginx debian phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

Всем привет. Неделю не могу решить проблему, все варианты в голове уже перемешались, хелп)
На ноутбуке стоит Debian 8 + apache2 + nginx (80й порт).
Установил phpmyadmin, mysql и прочее. Создал домен "test" он открывается, на нем функионирует php.

**Задача: "Запустить Phpmyadmin"**

**Запускаю http://test/pma/ - 403 Forbidden nginx/1.6.2**

в `/var/log/nginx/error.log` только

```
Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66
```

команды apache2 -t и nginx -t ошибок не выдают

в файле test который находится в /etc/nginx/sites-avaible/ (и есть ссылка на него в sites-enabled)

```
server{
server_name test;
access_log /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;
root /home/miha/opt/test/www;

location ~ \\.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;    
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location / {
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}    

 location /pma/ {
disable_symlinks off;
alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;

location ~ \\.php$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-pool-name.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/usr/share/php/php-gettext";
} 

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
access_log    off;
log_not_found    off;
expires 1M;
}
}

location /errors {
alias /home/www-data/mysite/errors ;
}
error_page 404 /errors/404.html;            
}
```

права 777 на папку где сайт /home/miha/ и /usr/share/phpmyadmin

файлов .htaccess не наблюдал в этих папках и выше

в `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` есть

```
include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

**Добаил ещё поддомен pma.test -там сейчас 502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.6.2 НО там уже favicon от phpmyadmin**

```
server {
server_name pma.test;
access_log /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;

location /
{
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$
{
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name; 
}
}
```

Содержимое лога /var/log/nginx/test.error.log

```
2016/07/16 20:57:07 [crit] 2337#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: pma.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", host: "pma.test"

2016/07/16 20:57:09 [crit] 2337#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: pma.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", host: "pma.test"

2016/07/16 20:57:13 [error] 2337#0: *4 directory index of "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: test, request: "GET /pma/ HTTP/1.1", host: "test"

2016/07/16 20:57:14 [error] 2337#0: *4 directory index of "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: test, request: "GET /pma/ HTTP/1.1", host: "test"
```

Comment: а apache в данном случае чем занимается?

Comment: 801м портом, который я прописал в ports.conf, если Вы про это.

Comment: я подозреваю, что к сути вопроса *apache* не имеет никакого отношения. вот и решил уточнить у вас: зачем вы написали про *apache*.

Comment: Отформатируйте нормально код. Читать невозможно

Comment: С ходу видно ошибку в строке `location ~ \\.php$` и неправильное использование директивы `index`. Я полагаю, что у вас просто не находится файл `index.php` потому что директива `index` написана так, что не влияет на `location /pma/`

Comment: Спасибо исправил на \\.php$, перезагрузил - но 403 по прежнему

Comment: @МихаилСоснин, а в логах /var/log/nginx/test.error.log что-нибудь есть?

Comment: @cheops Да, есть! Добавил в конец своего вопроса сожержимое. Пока анализию сам, большое спасибо за коментарий!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас указано три разных socket-файла, скорее всего какие-то из них не корректны или не существуют (в частности у вас виртуальный хост жалуется на отсутствие unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock)

```
unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
unix:/var/run/php-pool-name.sock;
```

Лучше не хранить socket-файлы в папке /tmp, там они могут быть стерты чистящими скриптами, запускающимися по cron. Лучше все держать в /var/run/.

Comment: Да уж, нубство мое зашкаливает,  по мануалам собрал... Прописал fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; всё заработало. От души благодарю за помощь.